# What does "plus" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning

> A good place to begin is to add or subtract one-half kg for every 20 kg of body weight, plus
> one-half kg for the weight of your equipment.

Does this mean to add or subtract 0.5 kg for every 20 kg of body weight, and then add 0.5 kg?

Comment: I would read it as combining 0.5kg for the equipment to the 0.5kg per 20kg and then adding or subtracting that total amount to something (that is, `±((0.5 × /20) + 0.5)`, where  is the total number of kilos). Hard to know if that makes sense in situ without the rest of the context though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

In this context, the word "plus" means "added to.. / and then add...", so the sentence means:

> A good place to begin is to add or subtract one-half kg for every 20 kg of body weight, **and then add** one-half kg for the weight of your equipment.